# Configuration error: Iberty library not found

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install `BAP: Binary Analysis Platform` in ubuntu 14.04. I am getting this error:

```
configure: error: Iberty library not found".
```

Comment: This is a question answerable with "yes" or "no". Why are you asking about the [capabilities of people](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3071/33055)? Are you looking to hire someone with specific knowledge? Would you not rather ask how to get rid of the error?

Comment: yes i am sorry for the question. I just wanted to get rid of the problem. I AM NOT ASKING ABOUT CAPABILITIES. By the way I did not know people also test others English here as well. :)

Comment: A clear, crisp question, with little ambiguity gets better answers quicker. I (and a quite a few others) don't just want to help, but also get/keep the site in shape (the former sometimes seems easier :-) )..

Comment: I updated my answer, sorry for the confusion (if that works, just completely delete your answer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Iberty` library is part of `libiberty-dev` on Ubuntu 14.04 (it used to be in `binutils-dev` on 12.04):

```
$ sudo apt-get install libiberty-dev
$ dpkg -L libiberty-dev | grep -F iberty.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libiberty.a
```

Comment: `apt-file search iberty`

Comment: @FaheemMitha And how do you find out how to install `apt-file`, as it isn't installed by default ;-)

Comment: Er, what? `apt-get install apt-file`.